# TSQL: Simple Pivot, Distinct Cells. Can't get it working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The Issue:

I have a table of two columns: Books's and Topics, and a single Topic can have multiple Books referenced to it, and vice verse.

I am trying to count the distinct number of  books occurring, and apply them to the pivot. The following code structure is what I have so far:

```
With dataSource 
as (
select book_id, topic_id
FROM BKINFO.BookTopics
    )
select 
[CS] as 'CmpSci'
,[PGM] + [NET] + [VB] as 'CmpPgm'
,[DB] as 'DB'
,[SQL]+[MYSQL]+[ORA]+[SSRV] as 'SQL'
, [XML]as 'XML'
, [SCI] as 'Science'
, [POE] + [FCT] as 'Lit'
from dataSource
pivot(
 count(book_id)
for topic_id 
in([CS],[PGM],[NET],[VB],[DB],[SQL],[MYSQL],[ORA],[SSRV], [XML],
[SCI],  [POE], [FCT])
)tblPivot
```

The pivot statements and other selections are there to meet the requirements of the question. (This is for an online course) The data output should appear as follows:

```
CmpSci      CmpPgm      DB          SQL         XML         Science     Lit
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
0           28          9           40          2           10          3
```

What am I missing here? i've spent about 4 hours trying to figure this out and it seems far too simple.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the current output that you are getting?
Also if you need to count distinct books then you should say specify it thus: count(distinct book_id).

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: The data output I am getting is what I posted above. I have tried adding distinct, but that causes errors when you put it inside the pivot statement. Adding distinct to the Select clause does nothing, as both columns become distinct.

Comment: @Astander: I am trying to get a distinct count of book_id, currently it counts books with multiple topics more than once.

Comment: Ideally I could step through the logic as follows: Count all *book_id*'s with a *topic_id* of x, then count all *book_id*s with a *topic_id* of y, not including the previously counted, till I've counted all *book_id*'s

Comment: If you don't want books with multiple topics counted more than once, then wich topic should you count it on?, the first one?, what is the criteria for this?

Comment: There is a topic weight for a later assignment, but this one does not require it. So I would go with the first one for now. If I could duplicate my logic above, I would follow the order of the 'For in' statement in the Pivot.

Comment: [CS],[PGM],[NET],[VB],[DB],[SQL],[MYSQL],[ORA],[SSRV], [XML],
[SCI],  [POE], [FCT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if the order of the topic in wich the book will be counted doesn't matter, the solution it's actually very simple, you just need to do a `MIN` or `MAX` over the topic_id when you define your `Datasource` table. So, it will be like this:

```
With dataSource 
as (
select book_id, MIN(topic_id) AS topic_id -- it can be MAX(topic_id) as well
FROM BKINFO.BookTopics
GROUP BY book_id
    )
select 
[CS] as 'CmpSci'
,[PGM] + [NET] + [VB] as 'CmpPgm'
,[DB] as 'DB'
,[SQL]+[MYSQL]+[ORA]+[SSRV] as 'SQL'
, [XML]as 'XML'
, [SCI] as 'Science'
, [POE] + [FCT] as 'Lit'
from dataSource
pivot(
 count(book_id)
for topic_id 
in([CS],[PGM],[NET],[VB],[DB],[SQL],[MYSQL],[ORA],[SSRV], [XML],
[SCI],  [POE], [FCT])
)tblPivot
```

You should be aware that the book is being counted only in the min (or max) topic it appears. Now, if you want the book to be counted on the topic following a specific order, then I recommend you to create a table `topic`, with an `id` int column in the order you like (in this case CS would be id 1, PGM id 2, etc), and in the `datasource` table calculate the `MIN` over that column.

Comment: Looks good from here. I was not aware of the min/max functions would perform that operation? I need to read up on them more. I think the only thing I might have to add there is a 'group by book_id' clause at the end of that select statement.

Comment: yeah, i forgot the "group by". I need to be more careful. I edited the answer now.